# understanding memory leak in a C program

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am trying to scan integers from user after scanning the needed size.
I represent part of the code, which I figured out using valgrind (returning The error in valgrind is: "invalid write of size 4") that causes the memory leak. The memory leak is caused by the function below the main.
The problem occurs when the user enter size and afterwards enter more data than declared, for example SIZE = 8 and DATA = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, I thought my code just ignores the extra data (and that was my intention), yet It all works well when I'm trying to debug it but crashes when it gets to the first free command.

I really don't understand why does it happen, can you help me out with it?

```
int main()
{
  int size = 0;
  int* user_numbers_array = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  int* second_array = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));

  printf("Enter size of input:\n");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  ScanNumbersFromUser(size, user_numbers_array)

  free(user_numbers_array);
  free(second_array);

  return 0;
}

int ScanNumbersFromUser(int size, int* user_numbers_array)
{
    int user_number = 0;
    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       if(scanf("%d",&user_number) =! 1){ \\testing for valid input
          printf("error");
          return 0;    
         }
       *(user_numbers_array + i) = user_number;
    }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you getting `size` after you allocate memory with a size of `0`? Wouldn't it make sense to allocate memory after you get the size?

Comment: "invalid write" does *not* mean you have a memory leak.  An invalid write is a far more serious problem.

Comment: You have one `\\ Testing for valid input` that has 2 problems: 1. It's not `\\ ` to comment it's `//` 2. You didn't check the other `scanf()`. Also, the space bar is either stuck and it doesn't work or it does work. And most of the time it does so use it correctly.

Comment: @iharob can you explain the point about the space bar please?

Comment: In your keyboard, you should use consistent whitespace in your code. I find it very annoying if I read code that doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've `malloc`ed the arrays *before* you've gotten the user's size! Your arrays are of size 0.